# Getting error in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

In order to fix large data set issue in BigQuery - i.e. following exception
Errors = {u'reason': u'responseTooLarge', u'message': u'Response too large to return.'} .

I changed one variable 'allowLargeResults': True 
this removed error but introduced another error in query execution. Error is quite generic and doesnt give any pointers on what it can be because. 
 Errors = {u'reason': u'internalError', u'message': u'Unexpected. Please try again.'}

Anyone has any pointers on how can I debug this and get more relevant information about the error/what is causing it. Will appreciate any help I can get here!

Comment: Can you share a job ID for a query that failed with "Unexpected. Please try again."?

Comment: @DannyKitt , Job id is job_mqUmJfuspWw4vjaYIUyO5nkeOFA. It works for small data set without the variable. Only when data set is huge, I get the exception and when I set the variable I get another exception.

Answer (score 2):

You're encountering a known bug in BigQuery, to be fixed in our next release. To work around the issue in the meantime, rename your field alias "Table" to practically any other identifier, like "TableName".

Comment: I have already implemented this in my code, yet I'm getting error

Comment: Can you supply an Job ID following the update? It may be that there were multiple issues, and changing the name only solved the first.

Comment: Now, I was able to get success some times but sometimes it failed  giving error :- "TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()". The JOB ID for failed case is job_zvfHJCKt1H0WA9L55nJbhrLLEXU.

Comment: The len() error appears to be a python programming issue, rather than the bigquery query itself. job_zvfHJCKt1H0WA9L55nJbhrLLEXU shows a success result, and the destination table received 8.575M rows. Perhaps you're iterating over a result value without checking for a Python None value?